# How to find (and copy) files using a list of keywords

Tags: finder, search

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders that have certificate files in pdf format in them. I have a list of certificates I want to copy.

I need to send a bunch of certificates - 66 out of 500 to a client.

How can I bulk search for the needed certificates? I have a list of keywords (batch numbers) that are unique to the needed certificates.

I'd like to paste a comma separated list of keywords (batch numbers) into find field in Finder and copy all the found files into a new folder.

Comment: Some friendly advice to a user “new” to posting answers…. The premise of the question is good, but the description is a bit unclear.  If you have a list of certificates in a document why wouldn’t you just search for that instead of a keyword search?   A clearer question will help in getting positive traction.

Comment: Where do the keywords come from, where are they stored? Do the keywords match the filenames? Can you add a screenshot showing this in Finder? Does it have to be a Finder solution or would a script running in Terminal be an option as well?

Comment: The question was badly worded, I hope it's clearer now. The keywords are contained in the filenames. For people who have textual memory terminal is a good choice! I need visual and constant feedback to my actions.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to replace the commas in the list with the `OR` keyword and paste it into the find field in finder.

So I copy the column of certificate names from excel to TextEdit, or better yet BBEdit. In BBEdit it is easy to find and replace `\n` (newline) with OR (don't forget to add spaces before and after the OR keyword in the replace dialog).

Now you have a long string of OR separated keywords that you can paste into the Find field in Finder. Then you can just copy all the found files to another location (or cut, useful for flattening subfolders into one big folder for example.)

Comment: Some more advice here…. This answer seems to missing some context here.  If someone was to follow your instructions as written, you would have a a single long string of keywords because you replaced the newline with “or” without taking into account spacing; it would look like `word1ORword2ORword3OR…ORwordN`. Aside from this logical error, it’s not clear why your doing a keyword search versus a filename search.   Let’s see how we can assist in writing a quality post. I’m happy to help, if you’re up for it

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Spaces are mentioned in the original answer though. For some reason if I do Name Contains my string of keywords it finds zero files.. Only if I use Matches, then again I don't find files where name doesnt begin with keyword. So that's why I use keywords.